# Update conditions to change index row

Tags: mysql

i have data from table Z

```
+------+-------+-------+
| id   | Data  | index |
+------+-------+-------+
|    1 |     A |     1 |
|    2 |     B |     2 |
|    3 |     C |     3 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

and change position index 1 to 3 and 3 to 1.
how query update in this case? if run query with condition index 1 and set value to 3, next condition index 3 and set value to 1? in result update id 1 and 3 value index 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET `index` = CASE WHEN `index` = 1 THEN 3 ELSE 1 END
WHERE `index` IN (1, 3);
```

But note that `index` is a reserved MySQL keyword, which is why I had to put it in backticks in the above query.  You should avoid naming your objects in MySQL using reserved keywords.